# jQuery return .length from AJAX query while removing LIMIT argument

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to work around some logic with an issue I have regarding pagination.

I need to build pagination elements based on a SQL query JSON array, which isn't a big deal, except the way I've worked the pagination is that only the "show per page" elements set by a LIMIT argument are being returned.

To try and clear that up, here's a glimpse at my code.

```
<form id="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="limit" value="5" id="hshowpp" />
</form>
<form id="userform">
    <select id="ushowpp">
        <option value=5>5</option>
        <option value=10>10</option>
        <option value=15>15</option>
        <option value=20>20</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

Which, when changed, sets off a jQuery

```
$('#show').change(function() {
    var ushow = $('#ushowpp').val();
    $('#hshowpp').val(ushow);
}
```

And then the AJAX

```
var results = $('#hidden').serialize();
var url = '<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&format=raw&' + results;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

So the AJAX returns a query of `index.php?.....limit=5` or whatever the user has chosen.

Now, that's the backbone of how it all works.  My logic issue is how to get around a pagination issue.  The URL that gets sent to the AJAX includes a LIMIT argurment, where when it hits mySQL comes out like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1=1 AND ...... LIMIT 0,5`, where the args for LIMIT are the "current page" and "show per page" values.  The issue pertains specifically to the where I need to show a total number of pages from the result that does not include the "show per page" limit argument.

If ANY of this makes sense...thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to break up the limit parameters into a separate hidden form so and `.serlaize()` each form either in tandem or on their own depending on what I needed to do.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPkCj/6/) to illustrate my method.